# ‘appid’, 'units' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am following this link ([Link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319243453_Building_an_IoT_Data_Hub_with_Elasticsearch_Logstash_and_Kibana)) to display live weather data on Kibana. I am using logstash to stash the live data into elasticsearch.

I used the logstash configuration explained in the pdf.

Here is my logstash configuration:

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "curl --silent -L ’http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5490223&appid=my_api_key&units=metric’"
    codec => "json"
    interval => 600
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@version" ,"command" ,"host" ,"cod" ,"id" ,"base" ,"coord" ,"sys" ,"dt"]
  }
  split { field => "weather" }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "weather-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

When I execute, I get an error like this

```
PS E:\elk\logstash\bin> .\logstash -f weather_data.conf --config.test_and_exit
Sending Logstash's logs to E:/elk/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-07-17T15:59:55,097][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
Configuration OK
[2018-07-17T15:59:57,966][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
PS E:\elk\logstash\bin> .\logstash -f weather_data.conf
Sending Logstash's logs to E:/elk/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-07-17T16:00:43,198][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-07-17T16:00:44,089][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.1"}
[2018-07-17T16:00:49,292][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,101][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,119][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,488][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,596][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,603][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,650][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,687][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,819][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,921][INFO ][logstash.inputs.exec     ] Registering Exec Input {:type=>nil, :command=>"curl --silent -L 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5490223&appid=6fe2c29d12b0cced47f3efa361dc1fe8&units=metric'", :interval=>600, :schedule=>nil}
[2018-07-17T16:00:50,989][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x59b6b4e7 run>"}
[2018-07-17T16:00:51,154][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
'appid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'units' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[2018-07-17T16:00:51,890][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
'appid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'units' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What wrong am I doing? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied the configuration from source, which, based on your editor preference, replaced `'` `U+0027 : APOSTROPHE {APL quote}` by `’` `U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single comma quotation mark}`. Please read [Right single apostrophe vs. apostrophe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711892/right-single-apostrophe-vs-apostrophe) on why its different.

In your `command => "curl --silent -L ’http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5490223&appid=my_api_key&units=metric’"`

you need to replace `’` by `'`, or manually write the entire url instead of copying it